Can the moisture involved in installing a vinyl floor cause mold?
The back room of my house is 20 x 20 ft.  It was originally a concrete patio with about 6 inches of drop from front to back.  So when the original owners converted it into a room, they built a wooden floor to level things out.  We recently removed the carpet back there and had luxury vinyl installed.
The installer spent quite a bit of effort getting the floor level.  This involved hauling in over 20 bags of redimix and screeting about. Then there were some bags of the self-leveling stuff.   Then the flooring was installed.
There's a set of 3 cabinets in that room with a granite countertop forming a dry bar.  (No plumbing.)  But I notice mold around the doors a couple days ago and when we pulled out all the glassware and other junk, the back wall of the cabinets was also mouldy.  There's no plumbing in that room at all so we'd like to know if bringing that much concrete and self-leveling stuff into the room would be enough to cause the mold.   Moisture had to come from somewhere.
(The other possibility is that the kitchen sink sewer runs under that slab.  We recently had to replace it and an outfit tunneled under the slab, replaced the  crushed sewer line and backfilled.  It seems odd to me that, now that the sewer is fixed (over a year ago) only now we'd have mold problems there.)
I'd like to know if this is a sort of common concern:  If you bring too much wet redimix/mortar/self-level into a house, would mold be a concern?
Edit:  The cabinets were originally set on top of the carpet.  Rather than remove the carpet, we just cut it as close as possible and the quarter round covered up any unsightliness.  So the carpet maybe absorbed a lot of moisture from the concrete and set off the mold...?

Not typically a problem. Bring in a dehumidifier?
